# Проблема с итеративной разработкой в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-core

Использую Visual Studio 2019 + asp.net core 3.1. 
Когда запускаю debug, вижу результат в браузере. Мне необходимо внести изменения в представление и сразу, обновив страницу браузера, увидеть результат. Но это не работает. Мне приходится останавливать debug и заново запускать, тратить время. Т.е. я вношу изменения не в модель или контроллер, а в razor page (.cshtml).

Как настроить VS для этого? Может проблема в IIS Express?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо через NuGet добавить в проект
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
Далее в Startup.cs в метод ConfigureService добавить:

```
  services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

[Оригинал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Возможность править в Razor pages (.cshtml) в debug mode, т.е. без перезапуска приложения, убрали по умолчанию в версии Core 3.X. Для того, чтобы править в real time можно воспользоваться "Запуском без отладки" или добавить в nuGet пакет: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** и обновить **ConfigureServices** 
`services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`